# Which one is better?: Do you need a/any/some help?

Tags: word-choice, determiners, connotations

How is the nuance of each one?

> 1. Do you need **help**?
> 2. Do you need **a help**?
> 3. Do you need **any help**?
> 4. Do you need **some help**?
> 5. **May I help you?**

And which one should I use to offer some strangers my help in stations etc.?

Comment: ["help", in this context, is a *mass noun* or *non-count noun*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/help), so you can't say "a help".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1. Do you need help?

This is used for directly asking if a person needs help without thinking whether the person actually needs help or not.

> 2. Do you need a help?

This is not grammatical. "Help" is not a countable thing, so an article "a" shouldn't be used. (I learned this from @user3169)

> 3. Do you need any help?

This is used for offering help when an asker is not quite sure if a person being asked actually needs help.

> 4. Do you need some help?

This is used for offering help when an asker is pretty sure that a person being asked needs help.

> 5. May I help you?

This is kind of formal, something you would be asked by a staff at some store or by an operator of some company on the phone.

It's probably not a matter of one being better than the other. I'm sure native speakers are choosing which one to use intuitively (even though I'm not 100% confident in the definitions I gave you in my answer...)

Answer (score 2):

> Do you need help?
>   Do you need any help?
>   Do you need some help?

are equivalent in asking if *someone* would like assistance, and is usually used after observing *someone* in distress.

> May I help you?

is formal and polite and can be more proactive by the speaker (depending on context).
It is asking for permission to provide help.

> Do you need a help?

is grammatically incorrect, however you could say

> Do you need a hand?

which means the same as

> Do you need some assistance?

Comment: Then, is there no slight difference in the nuances between "help", "any help" and "some help" at all?